# How to verify presence of scrollbar in textarea using selenium.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, textarea, scrollbar

I have a text area in web page which has no scrollbar initially. 
But when i exceeds the character by 1000, scrollbar is displayed in the textarea.

I have to verify the same whether scrollbar is present or not in the textarea when i click or edit the same textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client width or height will decrease if a scrollbar is added. So one way would be to check the size before and after.

Here's an example (Java) :

```java
Long height_before  = Long.parseLong(element.getAttribute("clientHeight"));
element.sendKeys("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww")
Long height_after  = Long.parseLong(element.getAttribute("clientHeight"));

Assert.True((height_before - height_after) > 10);
```

Or:

```java
Long clientHeight  = Long.parseLong(element.getAttribute("clientHeight"));
Long offsetHeight  = Long.parseLong(element.getAttribute("offsetHeight"));

Assert.True((offsetHeight - clientHeight) > 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But what if I have to edit a webpage or any document in which textarea is already filled with max characters. In that case how could i assert the scrollbar because in that case my before and after height is same. And it is great if you assist ne in java.

Comment: To assert the scrollbar, you could also get the difference between the offsetHeight and clientHeight. Have a look here for the different sizes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5AAyW.png

Comment: Everytime I am getting false as boolean even though offset height is more than client height

Answer (score 1):

There are ways you can do it.

1: As mentioned that scroll bar only appears if textarea characters exceed 1000, so you can check the length of text in textarea to find whether scroll bar exists or not.

2: Get the css value for textarea and check if `overflow-y` is `scroll`. Example for python selenium

```
element.value_of_css_property('overflow-y')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done similar verification with following way :-

```
 String originalScrollHt = element.getAttribute("scrollHeight");
 element.sendKeys(" 1000 words length string");
 String exceededScrollHt = element.getAttribute("scrollHeight");
 assertThat(originalScrollHt).isNotEqualToIgnoringCase(exceededScrollHt);
```

By taking **scrollHeight** as a element attribute, you will compare and verify scrollbar presence for a given element.