# How to verify that scrollbar appears in text area after entering 150 character

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

I have a textarea which does not have a scrollbar but if I enter over 150 characters, it will generate scroll bar in the textarea.

I want to verify that the scroll bars are generated correctly in my automation.

I am using selenium with Java.

Comment: Looks like a duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663005/how-to-verify-presence-of-scrollbar-in-textarea-using-selenium

Comment: @PavloZhukov I tried same code but some how its not working

Comment: Try to debug variables which you get and see whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using JavaScriptExecutor before, Hope this works.

```
boolean scrollVerticalExist = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;")

boolean scrollHorizontalExist = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollWidth>document.documentElement.clientWidth;")
```

Comment: how can I create reusable method using this java script which will check for scrollbar in perticular element which I pass in that method, I save all my locators as  @FindBy(css = "#terms-and-conditions")
    private WebElement generalTAndCInput; (for vertical scroll bar)

Comment: For instance generalTAndCInput is parameter which you are sending as parameter,
generalTAndCInput.click();
generalTAndCInput.sendKeys("Large text which exceeds more than 150 characters");
boolean scrollVerticalExist = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;")
if(scrollVerticalExist=true){
System.out.println("Scroll bar is displayed");
}
 else{
System.out.println("Scroll bar is not displayed");
}